# Simple question on $O(n^{-a})$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Say that

$ \mathbb{E}(\hat{T}) - T = - \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{12n^2}+O\Big(\frac{1}{n^3}\Big)$

where $O(1/n^a)$ is a quantity of order $n^{-a}$ ($a>0)$. Can we say that $ \mathbb{E}(\hat{T}) - T \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? In other words my question is if $O\Big(\frac{1}{n^3}\Big) \rightarrow 0$ as  $n \rightarrow \infty$. It would be nice also if you could provide the rationale behind the result, thanks.

Comment: Yes, $O\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right)$ denotes a function $f(n)$ for which there is a $C>0$, independent of $n$, such that $\left| {f(n)} \right| \le \frac{C}{{n^3 }}$ for all sufficiently large values of $n$. In particular, $\lim _{n \to  + \infty } f(n) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can say this, because by the definition of $O$ there exists some constant $C$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)<\lim_{n\to\infty}C\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)=0$$